# change TLFTextField link style

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, coding-style, hyperlink

I've a assets swc file that contains several TLFTextField objects, each one with it's style (font, color, size).

I use the following code to set a link:

```
var text_tf : TLFTextField;
var url : String = "www.stackoverflow.com";
text_tf.htmlText = "<a href='http://" + url + "' target='_blank'>"+url+"</a>";
```

This works as expected, but it changes the color of the text to **blue**;

What's the easiest way to configure the color of the text, without having to recreate all the TLF mechanism (ContainerController, Configuration, TextLayoutFormat, TextFlow, ParagraphElement, LinkElement, SpanElement, ...);

I was expecting something like this to work:

```
text_tf.textFlow.linkNormalFormat = { color:0x00ffFF, textDecoration:TextDecoration.NONE };
text_tf.textFlow.linkHoverFormat = { color:0x00ffFF, textDecoration:TextDecoration.NONE };
```

...but it doesn't  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you'll find an answer

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3358839

the linkformat have to b e added after the textchange, then it can work ( i tried it on an project and it worked, another person tried same thing on another project and it didn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

try using the formatResolver on your textFlow to assign a style sheet.